# Functions in critical sections produce data races in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I seem to have a serious lack of understanding of OpenMP concerning the use of critical inside a parallel region. My question is simple: Why does the code below
produce warnings with valgrind drd?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void A(int* a)
{
   printf("a++\n");
   (*a)++;
}

void B(int* a)
{
   printf("a--\n");
   (*a)--;
}

void f(int* a)
{
#pragma omp critical
   A(a);

   sleep(1); /* work done here */

#pragma omp critical
   B(a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int i;
   int a = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for
   for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
   {
      f(&a);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It is compiled it with:

```
gcc -fopenmp -g -o omptest omptest.c
```

And the valgrind call is

```
valgrind --tool=drd  --check-stack-var=yes ./omptest
```

My understanding was that critical sections should protect me from exactly the
warning I get. I spend 2 days now trying to figure out the error but I don't
find it. It would be very nice if someone could give me a hint on what exactly
I didn't understand.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The (repeating) warning on my 2 CPU machine is:

```
Thread 2:
Conflicting load by thread 2 at 0x7fefffecc size 4
   at 0x4007DE: A (omptest.c:7)
   by 0x40082E: f (omptest.c:19)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x4E45EE9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x4C2D9E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x5053E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
   by 0x535B39C: clone (clone.S:112)
Allocation context: unknown.
Other segment start (thread 1)
   at 0x4C2DF29: pthread_create@* (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x4E4631B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x400889: main (omptest.c:32)
Other segment end (thread 1)
   at 0x5326F1D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
   by 0x5326DBB: sleep (sleep.c:138)
   by 0x40083D: f (omptest.c:21)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x400895: main (omptest.c:32)

Conflicting store by thread 2 at 0x7fefffecc size 4
   at 0x4007E7: A (omptest.c:7)
   by 0x40082E: f (omptest.c:19)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x4E45EE9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x4C2D9E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x5053E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
   by 0x535B39C: clone (clone.S:112)
Allocation context: unknown.
Other segment start (thread 1)
   at 0x4C2DF29: pthread_create@* (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x4E4631B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x400889: main (omptest.c:32)
Other segment end (thread 1)
   at 0x5326F1D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
   by 0x5326DBB: sleep (sleep.c:138)
   by 0x40083D: f (omptest.c:21)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x400895: main (omptest.c:32)

Thread 1:
Conflicting load by thread 1 at 0x7fefffecc size 4
   at 0x400805: B (omptest.c:13)
   by 0x40084E: f (omptest.c:24)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x400895: main (omptest.c:32)
Allocation context: unknown.
Other segment start (thread 2)
   at 0x535B361: clone (clone.S:84)
Other segment end (thread 2)
   at 0x5326F1D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
   by 0x5326DBB: sleep (sleep.c:138)
   by 0x40083D: f (omptest.c:21)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x4E45EE9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x4C2D9E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x5053E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
   by 0x535B39C: clone (clone.S:112)

Conflicting store by thread 1 at 0x7fefffecc size 4
   at 0x40080E: B (omptest.c:13)
   by 0x40084E: f (omptest.c:24)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x400895: main (omptest.c:32)
Allocation context: unknown.
Other segment start (thread 2)
   at 0x535B361: clone (clone.S:84)
Other segment end (thread 2)
   at 0x5326F1D: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
   by 0x5326DBB: sleep (sleep.c:138)
   by 0x40083D: f (omptest.c:21)
   by 0x400902: main._omp_fn.0 (omptest.c:35)
   by 0x4E45EE9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
   by 0x4C2D9E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x5053E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
   by 0x535B39C: clone (clone.S:112)
```

I understand the warning as a data race on a, line 7 and 13 are the (*a)-- and (*a)++ calls.

Comment: What is the warning that you get?

Comment: I adjusted the description to clarify the warning, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Works for me (gcc 4.4 and 4.6). Which version do you use? Another thing. Try to make a threadprivate and run then. Why do you need those critical sections? Maybe it is enough to have one after the for loop?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. This is a simplified version of my code to reproduce the error. Basically, the counters are start and stop clock points to compute the running time. It could be done before and after the look, that's right. But now I want to know why it doesn't work. Are you sure you are using more than 1 thread? I can reproduce this error on openSUSE 12.1, 12.2 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: +1 on this question. I am in Windows in VS2012 and found that if I have a function that takes a `struct` as an argument, a race condition will be generated even if the entire contents of the function are inside a critical section, but *not* if the function is called from within a critical section. Changing the function so that it only takes parameters that are pointers to `struct`s fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just reading through the [documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html) of drd, in particular section 8.2.8:

> DRD supports OpenMP shared-memory programs generated by GCC. GCC
>   supports OpenMP since version 4.2.0. GCC's runtime support for OpenMP
>   programs is provided by a library called libgomp. The synchronization
>   primitives implemented in this library use Linux' futex system call
>   directly, unless the library has been configured with the
>   --disable-linux-futex option. DRD only supports libgomp libraries that have been configured with this option and in which symbol information
>   is present. For most Linux distributions this means that you will have
>   to recompile GCC. See also the script
>   drd/scripts/download-and-build-gcc in the Valgrind source tree for an
>   example of how to compile GCC. You will also have to make sure that
>   the newly compiled libgomp.so library is loaded when OpenMP programs
>   are started.

If you didn't recompile `libgomp` this could be a possible explanation of the odd behavior you are encountering.

Comment: Since I had this problem also with the Intel Inspector XE gui, I thought I didn't understand OpenMP anymore. Checking the Intel documentation also mentioned some false positives in the case that I'm in. Thank you very much for your answer I may try to recompile GCC and will report my success or failure.

Comment: This is it, compiling valgrind 3.8.1 solved the issue, it was version 3.7.0 for which the comment was still valid. Thanks a lot for the hint!